# Google Cloud Storage Transfer with a secured tsv url list file

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, transfer

I am trying to transfer the content or a publicly available url on a GCS bucket.

For that, I use the Google Cloud Storage Transfer api, and it requires me to perform two steps:

1. To create a **.tsv** file containing the **list of my public URLS**.
2. To **create the transfer** (here using the python api).

To launch the script, I use a service account that has Storage Object Admin permission on both the bucket containing the **transfer.tsv** file as well as the sink bucket.

I can only seem to make it work when the **transfer.tsv** file is uploaded to a bucket that is open on the internet.

Do you know if it is possible to put is on a secured bucket, and to give permission to the service account that creates the transfer ?

So far, all my tries yielded the following error.

**error**

```sh
PERMISSION_DENIED   1   
https://storage.googleapis.com/my-private-bucket/transfer.tsv   
Received HTTP error code 403.
```

**transfer.tsv**

```
TsvHttpData-1.0
https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/portrait-surprised-cat-scottish-straight-260nw-499196506.jpg
```

**python script**

```py
from google.cloud import storage_transfer
from datetime import datetime

def create_one_time_http_transfer(
    project_id: str,
    description: str,
    list_url: str,
    sink_bucket: str,
):
    """Creates a one-time transfer job from Amazon S3 to Google Cloud
    Storage."""

    client = storage_transfer.StorageTransferServiceClient()

    # the same time creates a one-time transfer
    one_time_schedule = {"day": now.day, "month": now.month, "year": now.year}

    transfer_job_request = storage_transfer.CreateTransferJobRequest(
        {
            "transfer_job": {
                "project_id": project_id,
                "description": description,
                "status": storage_transfer.TransferJob.Status.ENABLED,
                "schedule": {
                    "schedule_start_date": one_time_schedule,
                    "schedule_end_date": one_time_schedule,
                },
                "transfer_spec": {
                    "http_data_source": storage_transfer.HttpData(list_url=list_url),
                    "gcs_data_sink": {
                        "bucket_name": sink_bucket,
                    },
                },
            }
        }
    )

    result = client.create_transfer_job(transfer_job_request)
    print(f"Created transferJob: {result.name}")
```

And I call the function

```py
create_one_time_http_transfer(
        project_id="my-project-id",
        description="first transfer",
        list_url=tsv_url,
        sink_bucket="my-destination-bucket",
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to make it work.

When I uploaded the **transfer.tsv** file to the storage, I return the **signed url** instead of the **public url**

```py
from datetime import datetime
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_to_storage(
    file_input_path: str, file_output_path: str, bucket_name: str
) -> str:
    gcs = storage.Client()

    # # Get the bucket that the file will be uploaded to.
    bucket = gcs.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    # # Create a new blob and upload the file's content.
    blob = bucket.blob(file_output_path)

    blob.upload_from_filename(file_input_path)

    return blob.generate_signed_url(datetime.now())
```

This signed url is then passed on to the **create_one_time_http_transfer** mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably permissions in `storage_transfer.StorageTransferServiceClient()`. Create a role to access Storage and attach it to the service account running the Python script. Or put your credentials here `storage_transfer.StorageTransferServiceClient(credentials=XXXX.json)`

Comment: Same problem, I used the same service account to upload the tsv file to the bucket, and to create the transfer, this service account has the Storage Object Admin role on both the buckets containing the tsv file and on the sink bucket.